# Comparing two different arrays using shell script

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

How do we compare two arrays and display the result in a shell script?

Suppose we have two arrays as below:

```
list1=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 90 100 101 102 103 104)
list2=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 )
```

My requirement is to compare these two arrays in an order that it will only display the result as `(101 102 103 104)` from `list1`. It should not include the values `70` and `80` which are present in `list2` but not in `list1`.

This does not help since it is including everything:

```
echo "${list1[@]}" "${list2[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

I tried something like this below, but why is it not working?

```
list1=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 90 100 101 102 103 104)
list2=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 )

for (( i=0; i<${#list1[@]}; i++ )); do
for (( j=0; j<${#list2[@]}; j++ )); do
     if [[ ${list1[@]} == ${list2[@] ]]; then
         echo 0
         break
             if [[  ${#list2[@]} == ${#list1[@]-1} && ${list1[@]} != ${list2[@]} ]];then
             echo ${list3[$i]}
         fi
     fi
done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could also use this kind of approach

```
#!/bin/ksh

list1=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 90 100 101 102 103 104 )
list2=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 )

# Creating a temp array with index being the same as the values in list1

for i in ${list1[*]}; do
        list3[$i]=$i
done

# If value of list2 can be found in list3 forget this value

for j in ${list2[*]}; do
        if [[ $j -eq ${list3[$j]} ]]; then
                unset list3[$j]
        fi
done

# Print the remaining values

print ${list3[*]}
```

Output is

```
101 102 103 104
```

Hope it could help

## EDIT

In case of the 2 list are the same :

```
# Print the remaining values

if [[ ${#list3[*]} -eq 0 ]]; then
        print "No differences between the list"
else
        print ${list3[*]}
fi
```

Comment: Thank you.. This perfectly works for my purpose. But when I'm trying to handle a exception it not responding well.       if [[ -n ${list3} ]]; then
         real_val=$(echo 0)
         else
         real_val=$(echo "${list3[@]}")
         fi

echo $real_val

Comment: What kind of exception ?

Comment: -z too not working. Tried with both list3[@] or list3[*] in if clause. Any suggestion how this can be handled ?

Comment: suppose in list1 & list2 both the array contains same value then the array output will be null. So, what Im trying to do is - if the array returns null the it will display 0.

Comment: Thank you again.. its working.. Looks like the arithmetic comparison yield the actual result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`comm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) for this:

```
readarray -t unique < <(
    comm -23 \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${list1[@]}" | sort) \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${list2[@]}" | sort)
)
```

resulting in

```
$ declare -p unique
declare -a unique=([0]="101" [1]="102" [2]="103" [3]="104")
```

or, to get your desired format,

```
$ printf '(%s)\n' "${unique[*]}"
(101 102 103 104)
```

`comm -23` takes two sorted files (using [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation) here) and prints every line that is unique to the first one; [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) is used to feed the lists into `comm`.

Then, [`readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-readarray) reads the output and puts each line into an element of the `unique` array. (Notice that this requires Bash.)

---

Your attempt failed, among other things, because you were trying to compare multiple elements in a single comparison:

```
[[ ${list1[@]} != ${list2[@]} ]]
```

expands to

```
[[ 10 20 30 40 50 60 90 100 101 102 103 104 != 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 ]]
```

and Bash complains about a binary operator expected instead of the second element, `20`.

Answer (score 0):

[ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) associative arrays are handy for this:

```
list1=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 90 100 101 102 103 104)
list2=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 )
typeset -a onlyList1
typeset -A inList2
for elem in "${list2[@]}"; do inList2["$elem"]=1; done
for elem in "${list1[@]}"; do [[ -v inList2["$elem"] ]] || onlyList1+=("$elem"); done
typeset -p onlyList1
```

```
typeset -a onlyList1=(101 102 103 104)
```

Or similarly, start with all of list1 and remove what's in list2:

```
typeset -A inList1
for elem in "${list1[@]}"; do inList1["$elem"]=1; done
for elem in "${list2[@]}"; do unset inList1["$elem"]; done
onlyList1=( "${!inList1[@]}" )
```

Comment: Thank your for your input, but this is not working in my environment.